# Entity Framework: Ignore tags/special characters when searching items

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've database table which contains text with BBCODES

```
QuestionId | QuestionText             

 1         | What is your [u]name[/u]?

 2         | [i]How[/i] old are you?
```

I need to search all records using EF from a table that contains some search string regardless of bbcodes.

so, the following code return nothing:

```
var searchTerm = "your name".ToLower();
var query = _repository.GetAll().Where(question=>question.QuestionText.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm))
```

but I need to get the first record.

What is the best approach to ignore special tags when searching records?

Comment: Maybe you should add third column without bbcodes and perform search on it

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov thats probably an option...

Answer (score 0):

You can split the search phrase on white space, to get separate words to search for, and then use some more LINQ to find the matching items. Simple example using List of strings instead of your EF class:

```
List<string> Questions = new List<string>();
Questions.Add("What is your [u]name[/u]?");
Questions.Add("[i]How[/i] old are you?");

String searchTerm = "your name".ToLower();
String[] searchPhrases =  searchTerm.Split(null);

var matching = (from question in Questions
            where searchPhrases.Any(searchPhrase => question.Contains(searchPhrase))
            select question);
```

It should work, as long as none of the words you search for have BBCODES inside of them.